# react js project Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed. how can solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following warning.

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See react-unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.
```

[image: Warning image]

- Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
- If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memorization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at react-derived-state
- Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `px react-code mod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: Bar, BarChart

Comment: We'll need to see the code for Bar and BarChart to give an answer. If those are components you've imported from a library, then the library will need to be updated.

Comment: <ResponsiveContainer>
                            <BarChart width={100} height={300} data={this.state.data}>
                                <XAxis dataKey="Technology" />
                                <Tooltip/>
                                <Bar dataKey="Projects" fill="#0073E6" />
                            </BarChart>
                        </ResponsiveContainer>

Comment: We need to see the code which **implements** Bar and BarChart, not the code that uses them. And please put it into the question, not a comment.

Comment: @CoderFaruk i dont have the perfect solution for you, but, right now, I am assuming you are new to this react usage. as of now, i would strongly suggest you carry on with your react usage/learning/app building. Once you have enough experience with react, you will be in a better position to solve warnings. as you can see, these are warnings. for now, you can ignore it. you should solve it, but, I am suggesting, just not right now.

Comment: @CoderFaruk, Try using Reacharts 2.0.0-beta.5.
https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2102

Answer (score 0):

The warning messages are clear. I guess, you updated your react package to version 17 release candidate. Now, you have to update some lifecycle methods. You have two options.

1. Change the lifecycle methods as per guidelines in the [release notes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html).
2. Run a single command as mentioned in the warning, to fix the
   deprecated lifecycle methods.

> px react-code mod rename-unsafe-lifecycles